# ASP.NET download file using browser and redirect to another page at the same time

Tags: javascript, asp.net, redirect

Some time ago I had the following code in authorization routine:

```
 protected void Login1_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];   
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
            {
                // download file from server

                Response.Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
        }
```

`returnUrl` is a full path to the file on the server, so I used to download the file via browser download standard dialog this way.
But now I need to redirect user to another page right after authorization, at the same time when downloading file. So now I need something like

```
{
    // download file from server
    Response.Redirect(returnUrl);
    Response.Redirect("/");
}
```

I cannot find the way I can do that correctly. I tried a lot of approaches, but nothing helped. The important note is I cannot use the intermediate page like download.aspx that is used only for downloading and then redirects to the necessary page.
So, the approaches I used:

1.

```
Response.Redirect(returnUrl, false);
Response.Redirect("/");
```

Result: the file does not downloading, immediate redirect happens.

2.

```
Response.Redirect(returnUrl, false);
Response.Redirect("/", false);
```

Result: nothing happens.

3.

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + returnUrl);
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~" + returnUrl));
Response.End();
Response.Redirect("/");
```

Result: File is downloaded, but no redirect. When remove `Response.End();` redirect happens, but file is not loading.

1. The previous variant with following changes:
   Added:
   Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "3; URL=/home.aspx");

Removed:
Response.Redirect("/");

Result: File is downloading, but no refresh/redirect happens.

1. Used javascript for downloading file:

Response.Write("language='javascript'>window.location.assign('returnUrl','download', '');");
Response.Redirect("/");

Result: File is not loading, redirect happens.
Replaced `Response.Write` parameters with `"<script>alert('test');</script>"`. No alert appears, redirect happens.

Do you know, what's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got help on asp.net forum, right [here](http://forums.asp.net/p/1883533/5305880.aspx/1?Download%20file%20via%20browser%20and%20redirect).
I have placed the following code on the page the authorized user must be redirected:

```
<%--We use iframe and script below for downloading files by not authorized users via direct links--%>
<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        iframeFile.Attributes["src"] = Request.QueryString["file"];
    }
</script>

 <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="masterContent" runat="server">

    <div>
        <iframe id="iframeFile" runat="server" style="display: none;"></iframe>
    </div>
```

In code-behind of sign in page I've written the following fragment for downloading files:

```
string returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
{
    Response.Redirect("/?file=" + Server.UrlEncode(returnUrl));
}
```

Now the problem is solved.