# How to refresh a page after Download in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a C# code where i am downloading a file and ending it with Response.Flush() and Response.End().
After download is complete i want to reload the same page .
Can someone please help me out on this .

Comment: when you response.end you loose the connectivity.  you can use iframe like given in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15051479/713789

Comment: what if i want to do the all the work in C# code and not in cshtml . is there a way for that?

Comment: have you tried this ` Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);    `

Comment: @PranayRana please explain how you can redirect later to the page when file was downloaded on client side.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/74654/File-Download-in-ASP-NET-and-Tracking-the-Status-o

Answer (score 0):

If you download a file the original page remains there, provided the browser does not want to display it. E.g. a jpeg file would be displayed, a zip would not.

Considering all this, the page you are downloading from does not change and you don't have to reload it.

Even if you decided to reload, it is not up to the server to do it, but the browser to request. Unfortunately there is no way your browser would know in one window that the download is completed.

Comment: Re your last comment, true in general, but there are tricks you can use if you can set cookies from the backend.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've done this is to have the server set a cookie when sending back the "file download" response (with Content-Disposition as attachment etc.), and client-side monitor the cookie value in a loop (use setInterval) until it gets set, and refresh the form after that (you can use __doPostPack() or in my case, I was happy to do the refreshing client-side, as I just needed to clear some fields and show a success message).

Answer (score -1):

have you tried Response.Redirect() ?

where is the code?